# Connecting API to database

Tags: database, xcode, firebase

I am using this API to build an app (Xcode) and the maximum number of calls a day is 5000. The way I have currently built the app for testing purposes is to call the API every time the user refreshes the data. So, I am running out of calls per day. So, I was wondering how to connect an API to a database like firebase. Then update the data in the database maybe 4 times a day at a specific time. When the user would be refreshing, they would pull data from the database instead. I'm new to programming and am not sure if this is the best solution and would appreciate if anyone could direct me to more resources. Thanks!

This is the api I am using: https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/?

Edit: Also would something like this also mean I would build a REST API? https://github.com/unitedstates/congress It is a repository that includes data importing scripts and scrapers. I'm guessing this isn't compatible with swift but is compatible with building a REST API in AWS or Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS (Amazon Web Services). Their free tier allows many of their services for free (12 months, and usage limit) including the ones I would recommend you for this project:

1. Make an AWS account.
2. Use S3 storage buckets to host a datafile.
3. Use API Gateway to make an API.
4. Use Lambda to run a Python/Javascript in the cloud which connects the API with the S3 bucket (your data).
5. Use IAM to create roles and permissions for the S3 bucket, API and Lambda scripts to communicate.

Here's how you set up the API: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFsaiEhr1zs

Here's how you read the S3 bucket: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LvtSmJhVRE

You can also work with these tools to set up an API that PUTS data to the S3 bucket and updates the data regularly.

Comment: Thank you so much!  These resources definitely will help get me started! Also would something like this also mean I would build a REST API? https://github.com/unitedstates/congress It is a repository that includes data importing scripts and scrapers. I'm guessing this isn't compatible with swift but is compatible with building a REST API in AWS or Firebase?

Comment: Yes, with AWS API Gateway and Lambda (running scripts in the cloud called by the API)  you will make a REST API. I don't know anything about swift, but if you set everything up with ASW Services and Python/JavaScript (just follow the tutorials), you should be able to integrate it with the rest of the project. Good luck!